# Why is the first bar missing in my second plot in pgsplots when I set `axis lines=left`?

Tags: pgfplots

I want to make some bar plots and when I do this, I only want the lower x and left y axis to be visible and hence I set `\pgfplotsset{axis lines=left}`, but as soon as I do this, the first bar of my second plot is not visible anymore. Here is the MWE and I am curious what this is:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.15}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\pgfplotsset{axis lines=left}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ybar,xmin=-0.5,xmax=2.5,xtick={0,1,...,2},xticklabels={tool1, tool2, tool3},bar width=5pt]
    \addplot coordinates{(0,10) (1,13) (2,8)};
    \addplot coordinates{(0,3) (1,5) (2,9)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's visible, but the y-limits have changed, so you only see the top line of the bar. Add `ymin=0` to the `axis` options.